# Windows 7 fails using application/soap+xml while XP works with application/ipp when connecting to printer

Tags: windows-7, printing, xml

I have a Comtrend ADSL modem/router that shares a USB printer with IPP.

Windows XP connects correctly, but Windows 7 will not (as is confirmed by many frustrated discussion threads returned by search)

Wireshark shows that when Windows 7 is asked to connect to the printer, it sends:

```
POST /printers/hp HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Close
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/soap+xml
User-Agent: WSDAPI
Content-Length: 520
Host: 192.168.1.1:631
```

This is followed by the XML Probe, and this particular router just closes the connection in response.

Windows XP however sends:

```
POST /printers/hp HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/ipp
User-Agent: Internet Print Provider
Host: 192.168.1.1:631
Content-Length: 125
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

followed by a query (I'm not familiar with the innards of IPP)

To which the Modem responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

followed by a response that satisfies XP.

Is it is possible to have Windows 7 talk IPP and NOT soap+xml ?

All discussion threads I can find on this have people running around in circles, trying and trying again via the printer install wizard, when it appears that the problem is in the protocol language.

Comment: Excellent first question. Good details and well written. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I have since discovered more problems with the Comtrend router that make this print server practically unusable anyway, but the question remains open. Can Windows 7 be forced to use IPP?

Answer (score 1):

Just posting an update here so that other people can find this issue in google.

THere is a similar issue in windows 10 1807 , in that IPP will not be used, and the registry change doesnt seem to work either.

Issue: You want to create an IPP printer using http and the definitions fails with code 1793 despite the fact that the Internet Printing Client is installed and the GPO's preventing internet printing are not set.

Confirm by: If you pull a packet trace you can see that the user agent is NOT Internet Printing client but WSDAPI

Cache-Control: no-cache

Connection: Keep-Alive

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Type: application/soap+xml

**User-Agent: WSDAPI**

Content-Length: 520

Host: MyIPPHost:631

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe

urn:uuid:9332e7fe-3c0c-4d26-849d-e82b6a438840

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 to be able to use IPP it has to be installed first. Open `appwiz.cpl` and select `Turn Windows features on or off` from the left side of the window. The feature you're interested in is `Print and Document Services` -> `Internet Printing Client`.

The IPP support is not present in Windows 7 Starter Edition as indicated [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2462380).

Be aware that the Spooler service has to be restarted for this feature to become active, you can either restart it manually through `services.msc` (follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969708/en-us) article) or simply restart the computer.

After the restart you can add the  printer using `Control Panel` -> `Devices and Printers` -> `Add printer` -> `Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer` -> `The printer I want isn't listed` --> `http://192.168.1.1:631/printers/hp`.

Comment: Thank you mprill, however, please see the last sentence in my post.
Everything you suggest is mentioned on most threads you can find on this subject, and it doesn't work.

The problem is that this comtrend router/print server doesn't like Windows 7 sending the header 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml' and simply drops the connection. In fact in won't talk back to any HTTP connection unless it sees Content-Type: application/ipp

Comment: And no disrespect to mprill's effort, but precisely the reason why I posted on Serverfault and not on Superuser is that If anyone knows the answer to this, it's more likely to be a professional system and network administrator, rather than a computer enthusiast. I don't see why it was migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have found the answer in the mean time ... anway, for the record look here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/03/02/internet-printing-how-windows-decides-if-http-or-rpc-is-used-for-a-print-connection-to-an-ipp-server.aspx

In short, the answer comes down to this: In  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Settings` create a value called `PreferredConnection` and set it to 0.

This will (or should) cause windows to always use standard IPP to talk to your CUPS
server and not the M$ RPC IPP.

Comment: Please summarize the content of external links in your answer so future users don't have to follow it to know the answer.